# Laravel redirect to home when I surf the backend panel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with laravel 5.4

Laravel redirect to /home when I surf the backend panel or I create new category or edit category.

I did composer dump-autoload and php artisan cache:clear but It is redirect to /home again.

.env

```
 BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
 CACHE_DRIVER=file
 SESSION_DRIVER=array
 QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

config/session.php

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 1,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
| cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
| correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
|
*/

'store' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

 ];
```

routes.php

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'backend', 'as' => 'backend.'], function () {

        Route::get('/', 'Backend\DashboardController@index');
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'Backend\DashboardController@index');

        Route::resource('/category', 'Backend\CategoryController');

        Route::resource('/blog', 'Backend\BlogController');


    });
```

CategoryController.php

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

    use App\Repositories\CategoryRepository as CategoryRepo;
    use League\Flysystem\Exception;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Entity\Category;

    class CategoryController extends Controller
    {
        protected $category;

        public function __construct(CategoryRepo $categoryRepo)
        {
            $this->category = $categoryRepo;
        }

        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $this->data["categories"] = $this->category->paginate(10);
            return view('backend.category.index', $this->data);
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            return view('backend.category.create');
        }

        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $Result = $request->except(["path_info"]);

            $row = $this->category->create($Result);
            flash('Kayıt eklenmiştir', 'success');

            return redirect(route("backend.category.index"));
        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show($id)
        {
            $this->data["result"] = $this->category->find($id);
            return view('backend.category.show', $this->data);
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit($id)
        {
            $this->data["result"] = $this->category->find($id);
            return view('backend.category.edit', $this->data);
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
         * @param  int $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $PagesUpdate = $request->except(["path_info"]);
            $Pages = $this->category->find($id);
            $Pages->update($PagesUpdate);
            flash('Kayıt güncellenmiştir', 'info');

            return redirect(route("backend.category.index"));
        }

        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  int $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function destroy($id)
        {

            try {
                $this->category->delete($id);
                flash('Kayıt silinmiştir', 'danger');
                return redirect(route("backend.category.index"));
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                throw new Exception($ex);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: show us ur controller methods

Comment: I added to above now

Comment: try return redirect('/') instead

Comment: Is this incorrect routing ? redirect(route("backend.category.index"));

Comment: well u dont have that route defined as u can see..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this when you store the data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $Result = $request->except(["path_info"]);

    $row = $this->category->create($Result);
    flash('Kayıt eklenmiştir', 'success');

    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

When you update them redirect back at the same page:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $PagesUpdate = $request->except(["path_info"]);
        $Pages = $this->category->find($id);
        $Pages->update($PagesUpdate);
        flash('Kayıt güncellenmiştir', 'info');

        return back();
             //or
        return redirect ('/');
    }
```

Comment: @halfer thank you that you are improving my writing mistakes! Rest assured that I am going to use some real words from international American English! Keep up the good work!

Comment: @halfer speaking of, could you please provide me a link that explains the language level rules to be used in SO?

Comment: @Leo: there's several sources for that. [This resource](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) specifies a "correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability", and in relation to txtspk, [it comes up on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=txtspk) a fair bit. In general, the community is forgiving where people are making a small number of accidental errors, but deliberate errors (or so many accidental ones that something is unreadable) tend to get a poorer reception.

Comment: @halfer thank you I will schedule some time to read the rules. Apart from I always wanted to study English (my forth language that I can speak) so I would have known those rules better, unfortunately I chose mechatronic engineering.